# Does the probability of winning depend on the sequence of picking lotteries?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was thinking about a problem like this. Lets say we have 10 lotteries, 2 out of which win. We also have 10 people, they are in a straight line and take lotteries by turn after each other. Does the **probability of winning** depend on the **number they have in the line** they are in, I mean on the order they are standing in a line? 
Cause the first member of the line has the option to choose among all the tickets(including 2 winning ones) and the last one has no option but to pick the one lottery that is left.

Comment: Calculate the expectation of the person in position, $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter.

Visualize the outcome as a  binary string with weight $2$ where $1$ indicates winning.

Each such binary string should be equally likely. Hence the probability of each person winning is equally likely.